# Constructors and method chaining in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make method chaining work in conjunction with my constructors, but I am not exactly sure how to go about it.  Here is my code thus far:

```
function Points(one, two, three) {
this.one = one;
this.two = two;
this.three = three;
}

Points.prototype = {

add: function() {
    return this.result = this.one + this.two + this.three;
},
multiply: function() {
    return this.result * 30;
}

}

var some = new Points(1, 1, 1);
console.log(some.add().multiply());
```

I am trying to call the multiply method on the return value of the add method.  I know there is something obvious that I am not doing, but I am just not sure what it is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not return the result of the expression. Instead return this.

```
Points.prototype = {

    add: function() {
        this.result = this.one + this.two + this.three;
        return this;
    },
    multiply: function() {
        this.result = this.result * 30;
        return this;
    }

}
```

And then use it like this: `console.log(some.add().multiply().result);`

Comment: Ahh, of course, of course.  Perfect, this is what I was looking for.  I am wondering why there is the `.result` on the end of it.  I know it returns the `result` property.. But, how?

Comment: @Sethen: Well, its a good edit by Sidharth. at the end of .multiply() call, you return you Point instance, and .result property is resolved on that object, giving you the current value of the result property

Comment: @Sethen: `.multiply()` returns `this`. So it's the same as accessing `this.result` or `some.result`. `.add` returns `this` as well, that's why you can call `multiple` on it, which is also a property of the object. It's the same thing.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  It's just a property access expression basically.  Perfect, thanks!